# Better way to trigger events with Backbone/Marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

What's the difference between `trigger` and `triggerHandler`?

Does it differ from triggering events for elements using for example jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's put jQuery apart, cause it triggers events with its internal mechanisms.

They bubble if triggered on elements, and surely don't when on objects, but they trigger only jQuery handlers.

And for Marionette, the preferred way is to use `triggerHandler`, because it not only `trigger`s handlers, but also calls onMethod events.

See docs like https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.functions.md#marionettetriggermethod to learn more about that.